# Have a jar executable, (packaged with external libraries), how would I implement it on a server that doesn't have Java/JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, server, executable-jar

The server in question is a windows server, and I plan to run the program with a batch file on the command line. However, the server does not have Java installed, so is there a way for me to package the JRE(or whatever Java needs to run the program) into the jar file? Do I need extra applications/programs on the server?

Extra Info:
I packaged the jar file using eclipse, has around 3 external libraries, and works fine on my computer (that has Java installed).

Thanks!

Comment: Download the Server JRE from Oracle, it is just a Zip that you can unzip and put alongside your jar. That`s it.

Comment: There are several solutions, but they are all os dependent. If you provide more details as to which os I can provide how. Also this might not be a good idea for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distribute JRE with your JAR but you cannot pack JRE into jar. You should also take care of an execution script which would set up the appropriate environment variables and start your jar after that.

Below is the possible structure of the distribution pack:

```
-- App folder
|
+-- JRE folder
|   |
|   +-- bin
|   |
|   +-- etc..
|-- your jar
|-- execution script (e.g. start.bat)
```

Comment: If JRE is in the same directory with the jar file, and I run it on the cli, it'll run? I don't need to install Java on the server? Just clarifying. @Alexey R

Comment: @Maxxy JRE is a set of libraries and executables (relevant to the OS they are provided for). So you should consider this when you configure your execution script. It you will take this into consideration you will be able to run your application in CLI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, I have used [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) in the past and it worked like a charm. It allows you to package any number of jars and dlls (In case you are using native code) into one executable.

From their docs:

> Launch4j is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications
>   distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables. The
>   executable can be configured to search for a certain JRE version or
>   use a bundled one, and it's possible to set runtime options, like the
>   initial/max heap size. The wrapper also provides better user
>   experience through an application icon, a native pre-JRE splash
>   screen, and a Java download page in case the appropriate JRE cannot be
>   found.